# detect request from mobile app not from browser in php

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mobile

Hello guys i know how to detect mobile browser in php but my case is different now. if i am requesting php web service from app using NSURL than php fails to detect that it is mobile request or not . please tell me how can i detect mobile request (not browser) in php. i use

```
NSURL * url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://xxxx.com/detect.php"];
NSData * data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSString * str=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"Response is %@",str);
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you're using an `NSURLRequest` somewhere... Create a mutable request `NSMutableURLRequest` and set the header you want to check for in the PHP (using `addValue:forHTTPHeaderField:`).

Comment: i have my application on apple store which uses NSURLRequest with no header. Please guide me how to detect request in php with that case

Comment: The only thing you can do is look at the headers that are currently coming in and see if anything can help you.

Comment: there should be a way to do this.

Comment: It isn't guaranteed, but the USER-AGENT header often contains the word 'iPhone'. Your problem is that you don't set it so you can't be sure that it will always be there...

Comment: if i am using my webservice from browser than it says you are mobile but if send request using NSURLREQUEST than it says your are desktop